# for loop deducting a value from combobox

Tags: php, for-loop, combobox

I have a dynamic combobox that displays Seat Numbers. I have a for loop that deducts a selected value from the combobox.

```
function display_seatNo() {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 1";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Failed to fetch records");
 $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $seatNo = $rows['SeatNo']; 
 $totalSeat = $rows['TotalSeats'];
 $seatReserved = $rows['SeatsReserved'];

 $remain = $totalSeat - $seatReserved; 

 $length = count($remain);
 for($i=1; $i<=$remain-1; $i++){
   echo "<option value=\"$i\" ";
   echo " $i";
   echo "> $i </option>";   
  }
}

<select name="cbSeatNo" id="cbSeatNo" class="cb1">
   <?php display_seatNo(); ?>
</select>
```

Problem is that the selected value is not eliminating. Example:- Once Seat Number 1 is reserved, it shouldn't display in the combobox.

Comment: Pass the selected id in your function display_seatNo() and select except that value.

Comment: I do not understand...

Comment: what's the table schema like? What is in the table? How are seats marked as reserved? How do you know that Seat Number 1 is reserved?

Comment: table1 (ID (PK), SeatNo, TotalSeats, SeatsReserved )

Comment: seats are reserved after selecting seat number and when button is triggered

Comment: Have you heard about `foreach`?

Comment: yes.. but i am comfortable with for loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through all numbers from 1 to $remain-1. That is a logic error. Example:
You have 10 seats. Seat 3 is taken. You loop through 1 to (10-1 = 9). Seat 3 will show in the list.

Instead you need to fetch the actually available (or taken) seats from your database, not just a count.

Comment: I need to display all seat numbers.. once reserved, that particular number shouldn't exist in combobox

Answer (score 1):

Search $seatReserved for $i then skip it.

```
 $seatReserved = empty($seatReserved) ? array() : $seatReserved;
 for($i=1; $i<=$remain-1; $i++){
     if((array_search( $i,  $seatReserved)) !== false) {
         continue;
     }
   echo "<option value=\"$i\" ";
   echo " $i";
   echo "> $i </option>";   
  }
```

Edit: just in case 0 seats are reserved I gave $seatReserved a default value of array().

Comment: I'm getting an error - array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string

Comment: Hmm what is it returning, Ill craft my answer based upon that.

Comment: Yeah the default value should be array() not '', I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the result set.

Better change your query to something like this

Select * from table1 where seatsReserved = false ;

For each reservation, set the seatsReserved value to false.